# Puppet: possible to manage windows nodes in Live Management Panel?

Tags: puppet, puppet-dashboard

I have installed one puppet master server with 2 nodes (Linux and Windows), there will no error showed at all and the master and nodes can see and access eath other.

My Problem is that only the linux node is listet under Live Management. Shall I do something to this node also be listed and managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/) is the technology that provides the "Live Management" functionality in Puppet Enterprise - it's [recently gained](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/12555) support for running on Windows, which isn't yet utilized in Puppet Enterprise.

Per the [Puppet Enterprise 2.5 docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/2.5/console_live.html):

> NOTE: Live management and MCollective are not yet supported on Windows nodes.